# Typescript: confusion with accepting props in React functional component

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I'm learning how to use React-TypeScript, and I'm confused with how React.FC and generics work together.

So I have a couple of questions relating to the code below (a functional component returning a list item):

1.) Do you have to pass props as a generic? Or could you simply write

```
const TodoListItem: React.FC = (props) => {
//code
}
```

2.) How is it that `todo` is able to be destructured out of `<TodoListItemProps>` ?

3.) Why is a return type not defined? Shouldn't it be written as :

```
const TodoListItem: React.FC<TodoListItemProps> = ({todo}):TodoListItemProps
```

Full code here:

```
interface TodoListItemProps {
  todo: {
    text:string
    complete:boolean
  }
}

const TodoListItem: React.FC<TodoListItemProps> = ({todo}) => {
  return(
    <li>
      <label>
        {todo.text}
      </label>
    </li>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your function components two ways.

With only add the types to the function parameters:

```
const TodoListItem = ({ todo }: TodoListItemProps) => {
  return (
    // ...
  );
};
```

Or add it as a generic paramter to the `FC` type:

```
const TodoListItem: React.FC<TodoListItemProps> = ({ todo }) => {
  return(
    // ...
  );
};
```

If use use this component both will work just fine, but the `FC` type adds more to the component. If you inspect the react types you'll see that:

```
type FC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;
```

```
interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
  (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
  propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
  contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
  defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
  displayName?: string;
}
```

So from this you can see, that `FC` (or `FunctionComponent`) will infer the `props` for the component (from the generic parameter you provided, and extends it with the `children` prop), add a `propTypes`, `contextTypes`, `defaultProps` and `displayName` static field for the compnent.
If you don't use these, the first approach is functional, but the `FC` type will give you more stuff to work with function components.